# Odds of At least once over a series

Tags: probability

The odds of something happening are 5 in 100 and they are completely independent of each other. Before any of the events occur what is the probability that it will occur at least once over 5 events.

My friend says the odds are still 1 in 5. My assumption is the odds are 1 in 4. I think both answers are incorrect. His answer doesn't add any benefit of trying multiple times. My answer seems like it would create impossible situations if the odds were higher and would exceed 100% in some other examples.

What would the proper equation and answer be for this?

Comment: I had a typo he says the odds are 5 in 100 still.

Comment: Clearly if you have five tries you have a better chance of something happening than if you have just one.  It is still $5$ in $100$ for any particular try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the chance it happens is $0.05$, the chance it does not happen is $0.95$.  The chance it does not happen in five tries is $0.95^5\approx 0.773$.  The chance it happens at least once in five tries is $1-0.95^5\approx 0.227$.  That is close to $1$ in $4$, but not exact.  You might think the chance was $5 \cdot 0.05=0.25$ or $1$ in $4$, but that is the expected number to happen.  The chance it happens at least once is less because there is some chance it will happen twice or more.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! I'm sure that equation will come in handy in the future and for others. Thank you for your help!